# compiling ROS on Debian

Tags: ros, python, installation, rxtools, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to get started with ROS under debian. I followed the [install instructions for debian](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Debian) until the point where it is compiled using make. There I run into trouble building the rxtools with the following error:

make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/python3.2/config/libpython3.2.so', needed by `lib/_rxtoolscpp.so'.  Stop.

make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/all] Error 2

make: *** [all] Error 2

The folder 'rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles' does not exist in my ros-underlay folder! I also think it is strange, that libpython is built by ROS.
I ran into some small, solvable problems during the installation process before, but I could not find anything about this error in the net and am kind of lost here.

Thank you in advance,

Maximilian

[Edit:]
I did my research and found out that for some reason make wants to build libpython3.2.so which is already installed on my system.

A workaround for me was to remove the line **"lib/_rxtoolscpp.so: /usr/lib/python3.2/config/libpython3.2.so"** from the file **build/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/build.make** and change **"-lpython3.2"** in **build/rxtools/CMakeFiles/python_rxtools.dir/link.txt** to **"-L/usr/lib/python3.2/config/libpython3.2.so"**.

*make* and *make install* now runs without any errors but I do not think that this ugly fix is the right way to compile ROS. Maybe there is a problem with the CMake files somewhere and this could be a bug.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46363/compiling-ros-on-debian/) by [erniejunior](https://answers.ros.org/users/3423/erniejunior/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure for Debian, but for Ubuntu Python 2.7 will be the default until 14.04 ([source](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#python)).
If you are working with sources, than you might have used [rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep) to install system dependencies. rosdep resolves the dependency on `python` to `python-dev`, what for Ubuntu Precise points to `python2.7-dev`.

However, if you have `python3.2` installed cmake might look for `python3.2-dev`, which won't be pulled in by rosdep.

So, you could manually install `python3.2-dev` or force cmake to look for a specific version, e.g.

```
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
```

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2013-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on 2014-12-11**:
Thanks for your answer! It solved my problem :-)